# AKKA .conf file configuration to .properties file

Tags: java, akka, actor, properties-file, hocon

In my test.conf file I have the following configuration

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"

    serializers {
       java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
    }

    serialization-bindings {
        "java.io.Serializable" = "kyro"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to put this configuation in test.properties file as

```
akka.actor.provider=akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider
akka.actor.serializers.java=akka.serialization.JavaSerializer
akka.actor.serialization-bindings."java.io.Serializable" = kryo
```

When I create and AKKA ActorSystem using test.conf file it is working fine but when I am creating an ActorSytem with the test.propeties file as

```
System.setProperty("config.file", "test.properties");
Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
ActorSystem testactor = ActorSystem.create("testactor", config);
```

Here I am getting java ClassNotFoundExcpetion : "java

I seens the way I put the akka.actor.serialization-bindings."java.io.Serializable" in test.properties file is not correct.Please suggest the correct way to put this in .properties file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understood you want a properties file though I don't think you can declare a key in this way and also remember you have a powerful configuration tool in your hands.

I'd suggest to put all your default application configuration in `reference.conf` and override using `application.conf` hence you can just drop a specific `application.conf` on your classpath for testing on `test/resources`.

This could be your `java/resources/reference.conf`:

```
akka {
 actor {
  provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"

   serializers {
    java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
   }

  serialization-bindings {
   "java.io.Serializable" = "kyro"
  }
 }
}
```

And you put this on `test/resources/application.conf` or whatever you need for testing:

```
akka {
  serialization-bindings {
   "java.io.Serializable" = "java"
  }
}
```

When you call `ConfigFactory.load()` all files will be merged in one configuration.

I advise to read more about how to configure and override the configuration: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#Configuring_multiple_ActorSystem

Comment: I want to maintain only one configuration file either my test.conf or test.properties and not the both.In case of test.properties I need to know how to put serialization-bindings property.If this is not possible in .properties file I have to go with test.conf file

Comment: I am afraid you're out of option in this case. Stick with the hocon format.

Comment: Overriding default Akka config (the `akka` namespace) must not be done using a `reference.conf` as it will depend on class path ordering if those settings are ever seen.

Answer (score -1):

The Typesafe config library allows for loading properties objects and combining configs so you could do:

```
// or load it from a file using whatever logic you want
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("some.setting", "a-value");

Config propConfig = ConfigFactory.parseProperties(properties);
Config actualConfig = propConfig.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("test.conf"));
ActorSystem.create("name", actualConfig);
```

Update: as Leo pointed out in a comment, if you want to override `akka.actor.serialization-bindings."java.io.‌​Serializable"` that is indeed not possible with `Properties` as far as I can see because of the quotes.

Comment: This is not an option. He wants to override `akka.actor.serialization-bindings."java.io.Serializable"`. Properties keys can't have quotes afaik.

Comment: Sure they can: `properties.put("akka.actor.serialization-bindings.\"java.io.Serializable\"", "someval")` works fine. However there is a problem in that the Typesafe Config library does not treat quotes specially when parsing properties, it will interpret the dots in the full class name as sub-namespaces and it therefore does indeed not work for the given use case.

Comment: You're right, however I prefer a clean approach and embrace HOCON altogether. My 2c.